Query/Retrieve Integration Value from Address Settings in Apex
We need to retrieve State values (not statecode) from Address Settings (State and Country/Territory Picklists) in Apex. They are stored under 'Integration Value' property. Is there a way to query or retrieve this info?
The approach below is used for stateCode only:
Schema.DescribeFieldResult fieldResult = User.statecode.getDescribe();
List<Schema.PicklistEntry> ple = fieldResult.getPicklistValues();
System.debug('Picklist::'+ple);
for( Schema.PicklistEntry f : ple){
System.debug(f.getLabel() +'::'+ f.getValue());
}

Thanks in advance!

As you probably have seen, this has been asked before. Just out of curiosity: Are "State values" not usually configured as "State Name" in this interface? If so, you'd get what you're looking for by querying the label. Did you have a specific reason not to configure the "State values" that way?

You'll have to make callouts to the Metadata API to this info - it's not directly available to Apex.

@FelixvanHove different languages are used for integration purposes. Existing state code is also used for another use-case which prevents us from using it commonly. Thanks much both.
